# remove additional spacing from topmargin in the beginning of chapter

Tags: spacing

I got a simple doubt about topmargin spacing.

At the beginning of the text, after the Introduction, notice that there is a greater spacing than the one on the second page. I show this difference in the figures below:

But I need them to be the same size...  in the end there is a reproducible code, but without the text "bla"

[image: Bigger]

[image: Smaller]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[a4paper,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=30mm,outer=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large\thechapter.\quad}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{large}


\end{large}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Titlesec` defines a `\titlespacing`  command.

Comment: @Bernard yes, but even setting it to zero, the spacings are not the same

Comment: You can use a negative value, if necessary.

Comment: @Bernard thks. I tried, but nothing happens. Anyway, i wanted to know where this spacing comes from to make sure my document has the same bottom and topspacing

Comment: it would be helpful if you extended your example and showed what spacing yiou had tried. The baseline spacing to the chapter title usually has to be larger than the standard `\topskip`  simply because the font is larger.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I get the impression that this extra spacing comes from the word "chapter" that should exist there, but doesn't exist due to the command \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large\thechapter.\quad}

Comment: If the chapter number is  on the same line as the title, you should use the default style, not `display`.

Comment: @Bernard i changed from book to article and all seems to work... but now i need to change "chapter" to "section"

Comment: And if you tried with `report`?

Comment: I can give it a try